# couchdb crasehes on starting very first time

Tags: couchdb

What I did:

```
osx snow leopard
macports
installed couchdb

terminal>>couchdb 

messgae:

    =CRASH REPORT==== 5-Jan-2012::21:22:35 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: couch_event_sup:init/1
    pid: <0.78.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {file_permission_error,
                        "/opt/local/var/log/couchdb/couch.log"}
      in function  gen_server:init_it/6 (gen_server.erl, line 313)
    ancestors: [couch_primary_services,couch_server_sup,<0.31.0>]
    messages: []
    links: [<0.77.0>,<0.6.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: false
    status: running
    heap_size: 377
    stack_size: 24
    reductions: 127
  neighbours:

=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 5-Jan-2012::21:22:35 ===
     Supervisor: {local,couch_primary_services}
     Context:    start_error
     Reason:     {file_permission_error,
                     "/opt/local/var/log/couchdb/couch.log"}
     Offender:   [{pid,undefined},
                  {name,couch_log},
                  {mfargs,{couch_log,start_link,[]}},
                  {restart_type,permanent},
                  {shutdown,brutal_kill},
                  {child_type,worker}]


=SUPERVISOR REPORT==== 5-Jan-2012::21:22:35 ===
     Supervisor: {local,couch_server_sup}
     Context:    start_error
     Reason:     shutdown
     Offender:   [{pid,undefined},
                  {name,couch_primary_services},
                  {mfargs,{couch_server_sup,start_primary_services,[]}},
                  {restart_type,permanent},
                  {shutdown,infinity},
                  {child_type,supervisor}]


=CRASH REPORT==== 5-Jan-2012::21:22:35 ===
  crasher:
    initial call: application_master:init/4
    pid: <0.30.0>
    registered_name: []
    exception exit: {bad_return,
                        {{couch_app,start,
                             [normal,
                              ["/opt/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini",
                               "/opt/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},
                         {'EXIT',
                             {{badmatch,{error,shutdown}},
                              [{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,
                                   [{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,106}]},
                               {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                                   [{file,"application_master.erl"},
                                    {line,274}]}]}}}}
      in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 138)
    ancestors: [<0.29.0>]
    messages: [{'EXIT',<0.31.0>,normal}]
    links: [<0.29.0>,<0.7.0>]
    dictionary: []
    trap_exit: true
    status: running
    heap_size: 987
    stack_size: 24
    reductions: 172
  neighbours:

=INFO REPORT==== 5-Jan-2012::21:22:35 ===
    application: couch
    exited: {bad_return,
                {{couch_app,start,
                     [normal,
                      ["/opt/local/etc/couchdb/default.ini",
                       "/opt/local/etc/couchdb/local.ini"]]},
                 {'EXIT',
                     {{badmatch,{error,shutdown}},
                      [{couch_server_sup,start_server,1,
                           [{file,"couch_server_sup.erl"},{line,106}]},
                       {application_master,start_it_old,4,
                           [{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,274}]}]}}}}
    type: temporary
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a file permission issue. Try this:

`# sudo chown -R couchdb:couchdb /opt/local/var/lib/couchdb/ /opt/local/var/log/couchdb/ /opt/local/etc/couchdb/`

Source: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_OSX

Comment: This did not help me. Permissions were already set correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run CouchDB as 'sudo'.

```
sudo couchdb
```

Answer (score 2):

If `chmod -R` doesn't work, check the permission of parent directories.

My error was about `/opt/local/var/lib/couchdb/_replicator.couch`.
`/opt/local/var/lib/couchdb` was fine (755), but `/opt/local/var/lib/` was set to 750 somehow. `sudo chmod 755 /opt/local/var/lib/` worked.